# How to add new lines when using echo

Tags: stdout, echo

Why does the following command not insert new lines in the generated file and what's the solution?

```
$ echo "Line 1\r\nLine2" >> readme.txt

$ cat readme.txt 
Line 1\r\nLine2
```

Comment: Is `echo` mandatory ? you can use `printf`.

Comment: I didn't know about printf, with printf it works :P ...so what does it make not working with echo then?

Comment: Is `\r` include in output or it's part of `CRLF` newline?

Comment: There are many different implementations of `echo` command incompatible with each other. Thus it is recommended to use more standard tool as `printf`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo for extended overview of the problem.

Comment: In Stack Overflow, [Echo newline in Bash prints literal \nEcho newline in Bash prints literal \n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8467424/38108) has some useful answers.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### `echo`

---

An `echo` implementation which strictly conforms to the Single Unix Specification will add newlines if you do:

```sh
echo 'line1\nline2'
```

But that is not a reliable behavior. In fact, there really *isn't* any standard behavior which you can expect of `echo`.

> **[OPERANDS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)**
>
> > *`string`*
> >
> > > A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a *<`\`backslash>* character, the ***results are implementation-defined***.
> > >
> > > On [XSI-conformant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#XSI) systems, if the first operand is `-n`, it shall be treated as a string, ***not an option***. The following character sequences shall be recognized on XSI-conformant systems within any of the arguments:
> > >
> > > > `\a` - Write an *<alert>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\b` - Write a *<backspace>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\c` - Suppress the *<newline>* that otherwise follows the final argument in the output. All characters following the `\c` in the arguments shall be ignored.
> > > >
> > > > `\f` - Write a *<form-feed>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\n` - Write a *<newline>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\r` - Write a *<carriage-return>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\t` - Write a *<tab>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\v` - Write a *<vertical-tab>*.
> > > >
> > > > `\\` - Write a *<backslash>* character.
> > > >
> > > > `\0num` - Write an 8-bit value that is the zero, one, two, or three-digit octal number *`num`*.

And so there really isn't any general way to know how to write a newline with `echo`, except that you can generally rely on just doing `echo` to do so.

A `bash` shell typically does *not* conform to the specification, and handles the `-n` and other options, but even that is uncertain. You can do:

```sh
shopt -s xpg_echo
echo hey\\nthere
```

---

```
hey
there
```

And *not even that* is necessary if `bash` has been built with the build-time option...

> [*`--enable-xpg-echo-default`*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Optional-Features.html)
>
> > Make the `echo` builtin expand backslash-escaped characters by default, without requiring the `-e` option. This sets the default value of the *`xpg_echo`* shell option to *`on`*, which makes the Bash `echo` behave more like the version specified in the Single Unix Specification, version 3. See [Bash Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins), for a description of the escape sequences that `echo` recognizes.

---

#### `printf`

---

On the other hand, `printf`'s behavior is pretty tame in comparison.

> [**RATIONALE**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html)
>
> > The `printf` utility was added to provide functionality that has historically been provided by `echo`. However, due to **irreconcilable differences** in the various versions of `echo` extant, the version has few special features, leaving those to this new `printf` utility, which is based on one in the Ninth Edition system.
> >
> > The EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section almost exactly matches the [*`printf()`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) function in the ISO C standard, although it is described in terms of the file format notation in [XBD File Format Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05).

It handles format strings which describe its arguments - which can be any number of things, but for strings are pretty much either `%b`yte strings or literal `%s`trings. Other than the `%f`ormats in the first argument, it behaves most like a `%b`yte string argument, except that it doesn't handle the `\c` escape.

```sh
printf ^%b%s$ '\n' '\n' '\t' '\t'
```

---

```
^
\n$^    \t$
```

See [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/52934) for more.

---

#### `echo() printf`

---

You might write your own standards conformant `echo` like...

```sh
echo(){
    printf '%b ' "$@\n\c"
}
```

...which should pretty much always do the right thing automatically.

Actually, no... That prints a literal `\n` at the tail of the arguments if the last argument ends in an odd number of *<backslashes>*.

But this doesn't:

```sh
echo()
    case    ${IFS- } in
    (\ *)   printf  %b\\n "$*";;
    (*)     IFS=\ $IFS
            printf  %b\\n "$*"
            IFS=${IFS#?}
    esac
```

Comment: +1 for the `shopt -s xpg_echo` option in `echo` to use `-e` by default.

Comment: This solution does't work without `-e`. I am surprised that no one noticed that except perhaps @HaydeSchiff

Comment: @ha9u63ar - uhh... did you read this?

Comment: When executing `echo -e "package main\nversion = \"0.0.16\"" > version.go` in a Makefile on Alpine 3.12 and make 4.3, it will write `-e package main...`, instead of `package main...`. It will not recognize `-e` as a flag and just print it. Use `printf` if you want your Makefiles run reliably.

Answer (score 68):

Pass the -e flag to echo to make it parse escaped characters such as "\r\n", like so:

```
echo -e "Line 1\r\nLine2" >> readme.txt
```

Comment: A nice simple "-e" option to get escape sequences working - it says on another answer that `echo` is unreliable and doesn't follow standards unlike `printf`.

Comment: Make sure your script doesn't contain any literal \r\n, such as in a `tr -d "\n"` command.

Answer (score 12):

In all versions of bash I've used, you may simply insert a literal newline into a string either interactively or in a script, provided that the string is sufficiently quoted.

Interactively:

```
$ echo "Line one
> Line two"
Line one
Line two
$
```

In a script:

```
echo "Line one
Line two"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo -e "Line 1\r\nLine2" >> readme.txt
```

further usage possibilities:

```
man echo
```

Answer (score 3):

People have already answered adequately, but I refuse to accept a world where echo accepts any option other than `-n`.

```
nl='
'
echo Line 1"$nl"Line 2"$nl"Line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
echo ""
```

we can get empty new line i.e., double quotes without space.

Comment: Or just `echo` without parameter can be used in the same way

Answer (score 1):

If you have a character that is not part of the message you can pipe through sed

```
$ echo "Time on the next line:@$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%T%z")" | sed -e's/@/\n/g'
Time on the next line:
2016-03-25T10:12:39-0500
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to echo text containing exclamation marks (!) or single quotes (') you may run into some problems, therefore run:
`echo -e $'text/with exclamation.mark!and\'single-quotes_here \n more\\\text'`

so you don't have problems (make sure to still escape the one or more single quotes that are in the single quote string). Thanks to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025114/how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark-in-bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254120/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-single-quote-string-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo -e "line1\nline2"
```

This will print a new line.

Comment: This doesn’t add anything to the existing answers.